# What do I need to write if i want to get following json input?

Tags: python, json

I have a string here:

`string = '{{"Temporary Directory Path" : "{0}", "Download Folder" : "{1}"}}'.format(temp, download)` The temp and download varaibles are just file paths

I want to put it in my json file. But if I write it with python in my json file, I get the following text in my json file:

`"{\"Temporary Directory Path\" : \"C:/Temporary/\", \"Download Folder\" : \"C:/Users/myname/Downloads"}"`

How can I get the following output, without removing the double {{ ? If I remove them, I get a KeyError.

Comment: How do you save to file ?

Comment: _"if I write it with python in my json file"_ - how did you do that? The actual string created is `'{"Temporary Directory Path" : "path/to/thing", "Download Folder" : "path/to/other/thing"}'`, which is valid JSON; did you then use `json.dump` (which JSON-stringifies it again) rather than `json.dumps` or something? Give a [mre].

Comment: i did it with the write method @jonrsharpe

Comment: [Edit] the question, per the answer below if you did just `.write` it that should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already have JSON content (a string following JSON specs), you need either to

- write it directly

  ```
  with open("data.json", "w") as f:
      f.write(string)
  ```
- load as Python structure, then JSON dump it

  ```
  json.dump(json.loads(string), open("data.json", "w"))
  ```

Comment: If I write it directly, then I get the same text in my json as last time. But if I load as Python structure and then dump it, it works. thanks